# "Popularity Principle" in Probability

Tags: probability

I am having trouble showing that for a non-negative random variable $X$, $\textbf{E}(X\cdot I(X>\frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)) \geq \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)$.  Intuitively, I see why this is true -- if we reduce the values of $X$ to zero for all values below $\frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)$, then the "weight" of $X$ that occurs above $\textbf{E}(X)$ should make it so that even if all the rest of the "weight" of $X$ occurs at $0$ (which would make $\textbf{E}(X)$ as low as possible), then this would still cause the center of mass to be at least $\frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)$.  But I'm having trouble actually showing this principle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this might work for you:

- $ X\cdot I(X\le \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)) \leq  \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)$ as a bounded random variable
- so $\textbf{E}(X\cdot I(X\le \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)) \leq \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)$ taking expectations
- while $\textbf{E}(X\cdot I(X\le \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)) + \textbf{E}(X\cdot I(X\gt \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)) = \textbf{E}(X)$ by linearity of expectation
- so $\textbf{E}(X\cdot I(X\gt \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)) \geq \frac{1}{2}\textbf{E}(X)$ by subtraction

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Now I just have to think about how to turn my intuition into something like this.

Comment: wow do I feel dumb. And I thought hard about this!